# Is any underlying Hypergraph of a finite cubical complex contained in the Hypergraph of cubical complex formed by n-cube,with n sufficient large?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, hypergraphs

This question arises from simple observation that an oritentated finite simplicial complex must be contained in a sufficient large simplicial complex formed by n-simplex(Take n as number of vertexes in finite simplicial complex) But I don't know whether this property holds in cubical complex.

Essentially speaking what I want to prove is:
Any cubical complex(orientated or not) has an underlying hypergraph structure, is it a sub-hypergraph of an underlying hypergraph of n-cube?

Or in topology aspects:
there is a homeomorphism between any finite cubical complex in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and a sub cubical complex of n-cube complex in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Supplementary details:
For n-cube: it is an n-times Cartesian product of interval $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$

cubical complex: A  cubical complex K in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a collection of k-cubes in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that

1. Every face of a cube of $K$ is in $K$, and
2. The intersection of any two cubes of $K$ is a face of each of them

(This definition varies with articles, here is an analogy of simplicial complex)

Underlying hypergraph: a finite cubical complex has finite vertexes V, with all of its cubes as hyperedge in the hypergraph.

Comment: Do you require length preserved?

Comment: @coffeemath no, here cubical complex is up to isomorphism

Comment: followup Q: Is it required that the vertex and edge sets of the given simplex be subsets of the vertex and edge sets of some n-cube (allowing stretches of given edges)?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, for "A is contained in B" I mean an injective homomorphism between cubical complexes, so there is an induced homemorphism between the geometry realization of cubical complex and subset of n-cube.(If it exist)

Comment: Sorry for one more question: could you give your definition of a "cubical" complex? Does it mean e.g. that each vertex has degree 3?

Comment: @coffee I have edited the question for details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150903/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-wer).

Comment: I put more questions in chat.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to show that every simplex is contained in a large enough hypercube complex? Maybe this statement is false, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @MathieuRundström If every simplex is contained in a large hypercube then any finite simplicial complex is contained in n-cube. Then the question is true for the statement since any finite cubical complex has a triangulation

Comment: @MathieuRundström But I draw the 3-cube and 4-cube, it seems like there does not exist a complete graph, since diagonal segment does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I was too optimistic. It is a nice problem, I'll save the post, and maybe think about it some more.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Here we consider finite cubical complex not simplicial complex.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think it is indeed a counter-example since if there is a embed then there is a associated squares as two side of triangle but its diagonal does not exist in any n-cube complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $n$ cube consist of the collection of $n$-tuples whose entries are each $0$ or $1$  And define the $m$ dimensional lattice with bound $k$ as the collection of $m$ tuples whose entries are each in the set $\{0,1,\cdots,k\}.$ Given any finite cubical complex it is, for large enough $m,k,$ a subcomplex of the $m$ dimensional lattice of bound $k.$  Note that the only vertices allowed to be connected in the bounded lattice are pairs of m tuples which differ in only one component, and that difference is by 1. For example $(1,5,2)$ may connect to $(1,6,2)$ but not directly to $(1,7,2).$

Our idea now is to embed the bounded $m$ dimensional lattice in an $n$ cube where $n$ is large enough. To do so we consider a particular point $(a_1,\cdots,a_m)$ of the bounded $m$ dimensional lattice. Encode it at first into a $0,1$ matrix for which each $a_k$ forms the $k$th row of the matrix as a sequence of $a_k$ 1's followed by all 0's. The matrix formed, map it into the $n$ cube by placing the rows of the matrix side by side, from first row to last.

The subcomplex of the n cube formed this way will have the same vertex pairs connected as in the m dimensional lattice with bound k, namely two vertices are connected iff they differ in only one component, and that component difference is 1.

Comment: I think there is still some points need a careful consideration. First cubical complex may form a cycle path, like up, down , left and rigt faces of 3-cube, but lattice may not. Second "Given any finite cubical complex it is a subcomplex of the m dimensional lattice of bound k" isn't very obvious to me. there may exist 3 or more square intersect at the same edge. While 2 dimension lattice does not contain it. But I believe it can be fixed with some effort.

Comment: I am now thinking of deleting my answer. Mainly because of your questions, which make me uncertain exactly what a "cubical complex" is to be. A single n-cube has $2^n$ vertices, each of which is an n-tuple, and two vertices of this n-cube are connected iff they differ in exactly one component. In particular a 1-cube would consist of two vertices connected by a segment. So if that is so one could build seemingly any undirected graph as a collection of such 1-cubes any two of which intersect either in one vertex or not at all. [continues]

Comment: If that fits the definition of a cubical complex, then for example a triangle is one such, and clearly cannot be embedded in a hypercube of whatever dimension. One can also make such a problematic complex from three squares, which viewed from the side would look like a thickened triangle. Just as problematic.

Comment: The triangle(three vetexes and three segments) is a cubical complex(according to the definition in the question), I lost my sight on the simplest case .  Sorry for that essential mistake.

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient to look at "graphs". A hypercube is bipartite, but we can make odd cycles, the the answer to your question is no. Perhaps editing the answer with something along these lines is good? @coffeemath

Comment: @MathieuRundström The only type graph my argument works for is one which is a subgraph of an appropriate integer lattice, meaning for some $n$ the collection of all $n$-tuples of integers. Since the OP was it seems asking about a more general type of "cubical complex" it would seem odd if I edited my present answer to restrict OP's definition of complex to integer lattices.